# Override Jackson ObjectMapper config for certain POJOs

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an object mapper that is initialized with

```
this.objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

however, I need it to not do that for certain POJOs where I want their null value fields.

I've tried setting `(JsonInclude.Include.AWLAYS)` on the class and the field levels of the POJO but it doesn't work.

EDIT:
here is my POJO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
public class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("AString")
    private String aString;

    @JsonProperty("BString")
    private String bString;
}
```

i've also written a custom serializer

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyCustomSerializer > {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeNullField("AString");
            gen.writeNullField("BString");
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

i want the outcome to look like this

```
{
"AString": null, 
"BString": null,
}
```

however right now it's just like this

```
{
}
```

Comment: Dear @peachish11235, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the problem is that you check value for null. But value type is MyObject. What you really want is to check for null is value.getAString() and value.getBString() . Or whatever Lombok transforms aString and bString to .

instead of

```java
if (value == null) {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeNullField("AString");
    gen.writeNullField("BString");
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

your code should be

```java
gen.writeStartObject();

if (value.getAString() == null) {          
    gen.writeNullField("AString");
}
if (value.getBString() == null) {
    gen.writeNullField("BString");
}
         
gen.writeEndObject();
```